# Very weird forge error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is the weirdest error on forge I have ever seen. It seems when ever I launch MC with forge 1.7.10, I get this extremely weird screen.

Here it is: 
[image]

I tried to reinstall MC, nothing. I dont even have any mods installed. Here is the launcher log (it says nothing out of the ordinary)

Here is the log:

http://pastebin.com/LUZbpiHr

Also, I already tried

```
-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true
```

Still kept it the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only help with vanilla Minecraft, when it comes to tech support and crash reports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix this: My minecraft main screen words are green shapes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225760/how-to-fix-this-my-minecraft-main-screen-words-are-green-shapes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is empty. You might want to consider a texture pack to fix the problem (or edit your text). You also might want to copy the assets from your non-modded folder and turn that into a resource pack. (Then put the resource pack on). That should work.

Comment: It works. Weirdly, all I needed to do was recopy my MC assets and do that.  But, his answer works.